# How can I rebind stty lnext to ^q?

Tags: zsh, stty

You can type characters literally by [using](http://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/ascii-tty/)

> the "lnext" functionality (often ^V per default) in your tty driver

However, I bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to "paste" in my terminal emulator. (Since I don't use control flow) I'd like to rebind `lnext` to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>. I tried the following in `~/.zshrc`

```
setopt noflowcontrol  # Don't use ^s and ^q for control flow
bindkey -r "^Q"       # Unbind ^q from push-line
stty lnext '^Q'       # Bind ^q to lnext
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to rebind `lnext` to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>?

#### EDIT

I've done more troubleshooting, and can't seem to rebind other stty keys. I removed `setopt noflowcontrol` for testing, then tried `stty start '^A'` or `stty start '^B'`. Neither had any effect; `start` was still bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>. (FWIW I tried both a literal `^A` or `^B` and the character itself with `lnext` preceding it.)

Comment: You forgot to use stty to rebind the *start* character.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I don't need a start character because I turned off control flow, but do you mean that ^q can only have one function, and I need to unbind it from start? If so, I just tried `stty start '^A'` before `stty lnext '^Q'`, but it still fails.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Hmm… I troubleshooted a bit more. I've edited the question. Other stty rebinding fails too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stty lnext` only affects the terminal device line discipline internal editor (the very limited one you get when running applications like `cat` that don't have their own line editor). For zsh's editor, you'd need to use `bindkey` (`zle` does not do like `readline` (`bash`'s line editor) that queries the tty LD setting to do the same in its own editor).

```
stty lnext '^Q' start '' -ixon # for tty LD editor
bindkey '^Q' quoted-insert     # for zle
```

Note that you'd need to do the `stty` part for every terminal, and do it again any time the tty LD settings are reverted to defaults like after `stty sane`.

Some systems allow you do change the default tty settings like HPUX with `stty lnext '^Q' < /dev/ttyconf`.

And for `^V` to paste the content of the X11 CLIPBOARD selection at the cursor when in the zsh line editor:

```
get-clipboard() {
  local clip
  clip=$(xclip -sel c -o 2> /dev/null && echo .) || return
  LBUFFER+=${clip%.}
}
zle -N get-clipboard
bindkey '^V' get-clipboard
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly! FWIW the `^v` code works fine locally, but I prefer using the terminal emulator's ctrl+v function, because otherwise it wouldn't work in ssh sessions. Unfortunately there are only a few emulators that provide that allow setting `^v` for paste and `^c` for copy (e.g. terminator).

Comment: Should we keep `stty ...` lines in `.zshrc` or `.zshenv`?